Applications of the Inverse Function Theorem
I am an undegratuaded student of mathematics and I will do a presentation of the Inverse Function Theorem (IFT). What I need and ask right now is applications of the IFT that are not just "We use it to prove the Implicit Function Theorem or the Local Submersion/Immersion Theorem," but problems that the IFT helps to solve. The application doesn't need to be restricted to a very direct one that immediatily solves the problem, but one that you find interesting and that the IFT places an important role, whether solving or just making the problem simpler. Any idea is useful and will be well received.

Do you know what a submanifold of $\Bbb R^n$ is? If so, the IFT allows you to prove a very important result. A subset $X\subset\Bbb R^n$ is a $k$-dimensional submanifold if and only if it is everywhere locally the graph of a smooth function $\Bbb R^k\to\Bbb R^{n-k}$, where the domain is one of the standard $k$-dimensional planes in $\Bbb R^n$. (Try this for $n=2$ and $k=1$. You'll find numerous questions on this site where this has come up.)

To elaborate on what @TedShifrin said, the theorem is used to show that various subgroups of the group of invertible matrices (commonly denoted $GL(n)$) are smooth submanifolds in the space of all matrices. This shows they are so-called Lie groups, which have a rich theory and quite important in differential geometry and many other areas of math,

The infinite-dimensional IFT is used in many areas of analysis, notably to prove the existence and uniqueness of solutions to nonlinear PDEs.

@Deane Yours is an entirely different application. :)

@TedShifrin, it's morally the same.

For the length of an arc one uses an integral with antiderivative quite difficult to solve for the length, in terms of the integral parameter, but by employing IFT you can warrant the existence of the arc-parameter.
